# Determining the run length of elements in a list that satisfy a pattern

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, sequence

Is there a simple way to determine the run length of elements in a list that satisfy a pattern?

For example, consider the following list:

```
digit={0.2,0.9,0.6,0.6,0.7,0.4,0.3,0.2}
```

The second element (`0.9`) through to the fifth element (`0.7`) are all greater than `0.5`.

Is there a function to compute such run lengths? When I input the list(digit), it would tell me how many adjacent elements in this list are greater than `0.5`?

Comment: What should be the result if there are two such subsequences, for example ``digit = {0.2, 0.6, 0.6, 0.1, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.1}``?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
digit = {0.2, 0.9, 0.6, 0.6, 0.7, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2};

SequenceSplit[digit, {_?(# <= 0.5 &)}]
```

> `{{0.9, 0.6, 0.6, 0.7}}`

This example is quite small. Consider:

```
SeedRandom[4];
alist = Round[RandomReal[{1, 0}, 50], 0.1]
```

> {0.7, 0.4, 0.4, 0.9, 0.2, 0.3, 0.9, 0.6, 0.1, 0.7, 0.2, 0.8, 0.1, 
> 0.8, 0.3, 0.6, 0.8, 0.7, 0.4, 0.6, 0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 
> 0.6, 0.3, 0.9, 0., 0.9, 0.3, 0.7, 0.6, 0.2, 0.5, 0.9, 0.6, 0.8, 0.5, 
> 0.9, 0.7, 0.1, 0.7, 1., 0.8, 0.5, 0.7, 0.1}

```
SequenceSplit[alist, {_?(# <= 0.5 &)}]
```

---

Another solution is possible using `SequenceCases`:

```
SequenceCases[alist, { __?(# > 0.5 &)}]
```

If you have difficulty counting the length of sublists in the result below, please let me know.

---

Result

> {{0.7}, {0.9}, {0.9, 0.6}, {0.7}, {0.8}, {0.8}, {0.6, 0.8,
> 0.7}, {0.6}, {0.6}, {0.9}, {0.9}, {0.7, 0.6}, {0.9, 0.6, 0.8}, {0.9,
> 0.7}, {0.7, 1., 0.8}, {0.7}}

---

**For further study:**

Visualizing runs of two or more items that match the pattern, along with their lengths:

```
SequenceReplace[alist, 
 k : { Repeated[_, {2, ∞}]?(# > 0.5 &)} :>
  {
   Style[Framed[Length@k], Red], 
   Style[Framed[k, Background -> Lighter@Lighter@Yellow]]
   }
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Complementary answer:

```
SeedRandom[4];
alist = Round[RandomReal[{1, 0}, 50], 0.1]
```

Then

```
res = {}
Table[If[alist[[i]] >= 0.5, AppendTo[res, {i, alist[[i]]}], Nothing], {i, 1, Length[alist]}];
```

yields, for example,

```
{{1, 0.7}, {4, 0.9}, {7, 0.9}, {8, 0.6}, {10, 0.7}, ...}
```

Comment: From that, you can build functions such as counters, etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
l1 = {0.2, 0.9, 0.6, 0.6, 0.7, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2};

l2 = {0.9, 0.2, 0.9, 0.6, 0.6, 0.7, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.6, 0.7};
```

Grabbing the @eldo's examples and using `Pick` with `SplitBy`:

```
Cases[{__}]@(Pick[#, # > 0.5 & /@ #] & /@ SplitBy[l1, # > 0.5 &])
```

> `{{0.9, 0.6, 0.6, 0.7}}`

```
Cases[{__}]@(Pick[#, # > 0.5 & /@ #] & /@ SplitBy[l2, # > 0.5 &])
```

> `{{0.9}, {0.9, 0.6, 0.6, 0.7}, {0.6, 0.7}}`

The run lengths are

```
Length /@ %
```

> `{1, 4, 2}`

Answer (score 1):

```
al = {0.2, 0.9, 0.6, 0.6, 0.7, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2};
```

Using `Split` and `DeleteCases`

```
DeleteCases[{x_ /; x <= 0.5}] @ Split[al, #1 > 0.5 && #2 > 0.5 &]
```

> {{0.9, 0.6, 0.6, 0.7}}

A more complicated list

```
bl = {0.9, 0.2, 0.9, 0.6, 0.6, 0.7, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.6, 0.7};
```

```
DeleteCases[{x_ /; x <= 0.5}] @ Split[bl, #1 > 0.5 && #2 > 0.5 &]
```

> {{0.9}, {0.9, 0.6, 0.6, 0.7}, {0.6, 0.7}}

The run lengths are

```
Length /@ %
```

> {1, 4, 2}